# Large table in sqlserver

Tags: java, database, performance, sql-server-2008

I have web application that use SQLserver . In db I have one big table (3GB). All db have 4GB. Problem is that query from another  table (not that big one)  is very slow sometimes. Sometimes query need few second, but sometimes same query need several minutes.

My question is: can one big table slow down query from another table?

Because i em using sql-server-2008 express edition, with limitation of 1 GB RAM and 10 GB database size, could that be a problem? Would changing sql server edition solve my problem? There is about 50 users all the time that use application.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the simple existence of table A should not have any affect on queries against table B that do not involve table A. That said, if application X is querying table B and at the same time application Y is querying table A, and the query against A takes a lot of work, than that can slow down the query against table B, because the server only has so much power.

I can think of ways in which the existence of a large table could slow down queries against another table. For example, if the disk is fragmented with parts of small table B, then big table A, then more of small table B, any access against B has to move across larger sections of the hard drive. But wow, I doubt this would be a big issue.

I suppose there could be background processes, like accumulating table statistics for the optimizer, that would kick in on the big table just as you are running a query against the little table. Maybe someone with more knowledge of the internals could weigh in on a question like that.

Answer (score 0):

it could be RAM related, SQL server caches data in RAM and if a very large table gets cached, this could be at the expense of other tables not being cached and therefore slower to access from disk.

This is just a theory, but you might want to try out the queries in

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2393/determine-sql-server-memory-use-by-database-and-object/

How much RAM have you allocated to SQL server, and how many other databases/things going on?